# Matplotlib backend GTK3 Agg using Cairo?

Tags: python, matplotlib, gtk3, cairo, pycairo

I don't understand why while I' trying to use the Gtk3Agg backend and I end up with an error telling me the cairo module is not found.

```
    ** (simple_plot_in_gtk3.py:312517): WARNING **: Error retrieving accessibility bus address: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.a11y.Bus was not provided by any .service files
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "simple_plot_in_gtk3.py", line 5, in 
        from matplotlib.backends.backend_gtk3agg import FigureCanvasGTK3Agg as FigureCanvas
      File "/Produits/publics/x86_64.Linux.RH6/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib-1.3.1-py3.4-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk3agg.py", line 1, in 
        import cairo
    ImportError: No module named 'cairo'
```

I'm trying to run the [matplotlib/GTK3 example](http://matplotlib.org/dev/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_gtk3.html) from matplolib site.

Answer (score 2):

Installing [Python binging for Python](https://cairographics.org/pycairo/) works:

```py
$ pip install pycairo
```

Comment: I tried to install pycairo. But it gave an error:



Failed to build pycairo. ERROR: Could not build wheels for pycairo which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Comment: what about `pip3` ? You tried that for python3 ?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the `backend_gtk3agg.py` file, you'll see that the first lines in the file are;

```
import cairo
import numpy as np
import sys
import warnings

import backend_agg
import backend_gtk3
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib import transforms
```

So, yes, the gtk3agg backend requires the [cairo library](http://cairographics.org/) and its [Python bindings](http://cairographics.org/pycairo/). And numpy.

It uses Cairo for ImageSurface buffers, because that is something AGG [does not provide](http://www.antigrain.com/doc/basic_renderers/basic_renderers.agdoc.html#toc0002). I do not know why the gtk3agg developers chose this method. Presumably because it was convenient.

Comment: Yes i saw this and that's the point. AGG is a rendering library that is equivalent to Cairo. The Agg backend should use Agg and not cairo (there is also a cairo backend).

Comment: AGG doesn't provide image buffers. See updated answer.